# Could JavaScript variables be used as JSDoc types and why do so?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I'm checking [this](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/master/examples/vanilla-es6) code and I've encountered [this](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/4e301c7014093505dcf6678c8f97a5e8dee2d250/examples/vanilla-es6/src/item.js#L32) snippet:

```js
/**
 * Enum containing a known-empty record type, matching only empty records unlike Object.
 *
 * @enum {Object}
 */
const Empty = {
    Record: {}
};

/**
 * Empty ItemQuery type, based on the Empty @enum.
 *
 * @typedef {Empty}
 */
export var EmptyItemQuery;

/**
 * Reference to the only EmptyItemQuery instance.
 *
 * @type {EmptyItemQuery}
 */
export const emptyItemQuery = Empty.Record;
```

1. I used to think that JSDoc types must be defined in JSDoc comments only, but this code has used the `Empty` variable and the `EmptyItemQuery` variable (which are non-comment regular JavaScript variables) as types! I've checked [JSDoc's doc](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html) and couldn't find a similar example, so I wonder if it's actually what I think it is? Or I'm misinterpreting it?
2. For the `emptyItemQuery`, why not just do: `export const emptyItemQuery = {};`? Is the `Empty` object really needed here? What  for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. JavaScript does not know these types. As you said in your comment, they are only indicators for the IDE to help with code completion.

The author exports the object "emptyItemQuery" as an initialization value.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {EmptyItemQuery} arg1 
 *
 */
function a1(arg1 = emptyItemQuery){}
```

Their naming convention will help contributors differentiate between generic and non-generic objects.
They want to emphasize that the format to use for an empty query is {}, with whatever driver they used or created.

**"Empty"** being an enum, they will likely add more definitions in the future.

For instance:

```js
export const Empty = {
    Record: {},
    Table: "*",
    Something: {}
};

export const emptyItemQuery = Empty.Record;
export const emptyTableQuery = Empty.Table;
export const emptySomethingQuery = Empty.Something;
```

The issue is that the enum Empty contains only **1 value**. So, it makes the code look a bit more obscure as an enum with only one element defies the point.

---

Note that in the line:

```
export var EmptyItemQuery;
```

There is no use in exporting **"EmptyItemQuery"**. It's likely a tiny mistake, as the symbol is never imported throughout the entire repository.

---

Finally, I think JsDocs is a fabulous tool.
I always use it as it pushes code completion to a high level. It allows you to code quickly still (as you're using JavaScript) while having some type-checking abilities (without extra noise).

Comment: Yes I like JSDoc a lot too, it's like a lite version of TypeScript already baked into the editor. Thanks, I've got the answer to my second question. However, I'm still a bit confused about your answer to the first question: "_JavaScript does not know these types._", --> I guess you've answered my first question in the opposite direction... I know JavaScript does not know about JSDoc types, my point is the other way around, i.e., how come JavaScript variables are used in the JSDoc? Is it a valid thing to do?

Comment: When I generated the doc with JsDocs, it did not seem like it parsed the code, only the comment. Did you try to generate the documentation?
Also, even with the extra parsing from my IDEs, I have poor code completion with the example. I hope it's what you mean.

Comment: No, I didn't generate the documentation. My question was basically about the syntax with which they've defined the types, which is not according to this syntax `@typedef [<type>] <namepath>` from here: [@use JSDoc @typedef](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html#syntax), (they've not passed any namepath and have used JavaScript variables as names and it's working! while it's not documented in the jsdoc.app link I just shared). I've tried it on VSCode though, and I have perfect code completion, so it's probably OK and a valid syntax. Thank you so much. I'll mark your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: Cool, It's possible that JsDoc does some basic parsing on the source. I always try to document JsDoc in the comment as much as I can. 
But, still great to investigate JsDoc capabilities.